# How to remove the arrows icons from a Material UI TextField

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, icons, textfield

I need to remove the right icons that are the up and down arrows from a Material UI TextField that I modified from the Material UI documentations (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) Highlights section.

I tried some solutions from stack overflow like ([Remove the arrow and cross that appears for TextField type=“time” material-ui React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101519/remove-the-arrow-and-cross-that-appears-for-textfield-type-time-material-ui-re)) and ([Remove the arrow and cross that appears for TextField type=“time” material-ui React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101519/remove-the-arrow-and-cross-that-appears-for-textfield-type-time-material-ui-re)) but they didn't work and, I ended up with the following code:

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import parse from "autosuggest-highlight/parse";
import match from "autosuggest-highlight/match";
import { InputAdornment, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  noBorder: {
    border: "none"
  }
}));

export default function Highlights() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          autoFocus
          classes={{ notchedOutline: classes.input }}
          // onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
          placeholder="Search..."
          type="search"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: { notchedOutline: classes.noBorder }
          }}
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(option, { inputValue }) => {
        const matches = match(option.title, inputValue);
        const parts = parse(option.title, matches);

        return (
          <div>
            {parts.map((part, index) => (
              <span
                key={index}
                style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}
              >
                {part.text}
              </span>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  { title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind", year: 2004 },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

styles.css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type="search"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

/* remove outsideof arrows button */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-outside-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [document](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo) you need to add freesolo

```
return (
    <Autocomplete
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      options={top100Films}
      freeSolo
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          autoFocus
          classes={{ notchedOutline: classes.input }}
          // onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
          placeholder="Search..."
          type="search"
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: { notchedOutline: classes.noBorder }
          }}
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(option, { inputValue }) => {
        const matches = match(option.title, inputValue);
        const parts = parse(option.title, matches);

        return (
          <div>
            {parts.map((part, index) => (
              <span
                key={index}
                style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}
              >
                {part.text}
              </span>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! It Worked! That's a very simple and great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this css code (for this link https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete)

```
.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator {
 display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **dont need freesolo**.

```
<Autocomplete>
...
popupIcon={null}
/>
```

By this you can remove the ArrowDownIcon but keep in mind what is the idea behind the Autocomplete free solo and combo box:

> The widget(Material UI Autocomplete) is useful for setting the value of a single-line textbox in
> one of two types of scenarios:
>
> 1. The value for the textbox must be chosen from a predefined set of
>    allowed values, e.g., a location field must contain a valid location
>    name: combo box.
> 2. The textbox may contain any arbitrary value, but it
>    is advantageous to suggest possible values to the user, e.g., a search
>    field may suggest similar or previous searches to save the user time:
>    free solo.