# Material UI: TextField Alarm Clock change to Another Icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have `TextField`. In that the Material UI has `Alarm Clock` icon.

The material UI docs have like this:

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate>
  <TextField
    id="time"
    label="Alarm clock"
    type="time"
    defaultValue="07:30"
    className={classes.textField}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
    }}
    inputProps={{
      step: 300, // 5 min
    }}
  />
</form>
```

What I have designed is like this:

```
<TextField
  id="time"
  type="time"
  style={{
    width: "148px",
    marginLeft: 4,
    marginRight: 6,
    padding: "2px 0px 3px 6px",
  }}
  defaultValue="03:30"
  value={timeChange}
  onChange={handleTimeChange}
  className={classes.textField}
  color="secondary"
  InputProps={{
    disableUnderline: true,
    endAdornment: <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ color: "gray" }} />,
    classes: {
      input: classes.floatingLabelFocusStyle,
    },
    // className: classes.input,
  }}
/>;
```

And added some CSS to it:

```
   input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
          background: none;
   }
```

Which I'm getting:

[image]

Is there a way, that I can make `ExpandMoreIcon` behave like the alarm clock on click and open the pop up to show time picker?

I don't want to show the alarm clock icon. I just want the functionality of alarm clock in `ExpandMoreIcon` icon?

Is there any fix to it?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const [displayPicker, setDisplayPicker] = React.useState(false);      

<TextField
        id="time"
        type="time"
        style={{
          width: '148px',
          marginLeft: 4,
          marginRight: 6,
          padding: '2px 0px 3px 6px',
        }}
        defaultValue="03:30"
        value={timeChange}
        onChange={handleTimeChange}
        focused={displayPicker}
        className={classes.textField}
        color="secondary"
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ color: 'gray' }} />,
          onFocus: () => setDisplayPicker(true),
          onBlur: () => setDisplayPicker(false),
          classes: {
            input: classes.floatingLabelFocusStyle,
          },
        }}
      />
```

Comment: This is based on code provided by material UI docs at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/FormControl/FormControl.js

Comment: Can you do something in CSS? Can you replace the background with `ExpandMoreIcon`? Because the code you provided is not working on arrow down button. The popup for time picker is not popping up on arrow down button click

Comment: try passing the focused value inside the InputProps object. I have to start work now and will not be able to test this for you further, I'm sorry. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add onClick to the endAdornment under InputProps to adjust the functionality.

Try like this..

```
InputProps={{
          endAdornment: <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ color: "gray" }} onClick={FunctionToOpenTimePicker}/>,
        }}
```

OR TRY

```
    InputProps={{
          endAdornment: <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ color: "gray" }}/>, onClick: () => FunctionToOpenTimePicker
        }}
```

I know also that we have used onFocus/onBlur in some of our code with the adornments.

```
    InputProps={{
      endAdornment: <ExpandMoreIcon style={{ color: "gray" }}/>,
      onFocus: () => {if (!thing1) setThing2State(true)}, 
      onBlue: () => {if (!thing1) setThing2State(false)}
    }}
```

For hiding the clock icon, that may require CSS like in the examples shown here

[Remove the arrow and cross that appears for TextField type=“time” material-ui React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101519/remove-the-arrow-and-cross-that-appears-for-textfield-type-time-material-ui-re)

Comment: what is thing1 and thing2state?. I have set the alarm clock display to none. The functionality I want is to implement the alarmclock click functionality to the `ExpandMoreIcon`. Can you please provide me with complete code or information?

Comment: What should I have to write in `FunctionToOpenTimePicker`??

Comment: Those were intended to be throwaway names of variables/functions that you could replace with your own. Looking into https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/FormControl/FormControl.js it seems that the component will use the 'focused' prop to determine whether to display the picker or hide the picker. Here's my suggestion.

Create a state variable using the useState variable. This variable should be true or false. Pass the variable to the TextField component, and use the onFocus and onBlur example I provided

Comment: so setThing2State should be second state??

Comment: I've added an additional answer that should provide you the code you need